# Apache virtual hosts https works but http takes to default virtual host only

Tags: apache, apache2, apache2.4

I'm using amazon linux with apache (Apache/2.4.25 (Amazon)). I have a few domains and a few handful of subdomains. I use letsencrypt/cerbot for ssl certificates. This works. I can access https without issue. However, I cannot access any of my non default http virtual hosts. They all re-route to the default virtual host. I've only found a few other posts like this without resolution and this appears to be difficult to search for. Letsencrypt complained that I needed separate files for virtual hosts so thats what i did for http and https. I have ended up moving all of the http ones into the httpd.conf and that doesn't work either. I have "A" records for my domains and subdomains as well. What am I missing?

```
###Begin httpd.conf###

ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

Listen 80

Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

User nona_yo_biz
Group nona_yo_biz

ServerAdmin support@example.com

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride All
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Load config files in the "/etc/httpd/conf.d" directory, if any.
# This is where my ssl files are stored
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf

#Some other module crap etc

#Some other AWS settings

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin support@example.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/basesite"
ServerName basesite.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin support@example.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/sub1example"
ServerName sub1.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin support@example.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/sub2example"
ServerName sub2.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin support@example.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/example"
ServerName example.com
</VirtualHost>

###End httpd.conf###

###BEGIN ssl.conf###

Listen 443 https

#Some other stuff

<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/basesite"
ServerName basesite.com:443
ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
LogLevel warn
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv3
SSLProxyProtocol all -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
#Some other stuff
CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
ServerAdmin support@example.com
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/basesite.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/basesite.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>

###END ssl.conf

###Separate conf file for vhost###

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin support@example.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/sub1example"
ServerName sub1.example.com:443
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/basesite.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/basesite.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>

###Separate conf file for vhost###

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin support@example.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/sub2example"
ServerName sub2.example.com:443
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/basesite.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/basesite.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>

###Separate conf file for vhost###

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin support@example.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/example"
ServerName example.com:443
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/basesite.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/basesite.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

**Edit apachectl -S output**

```
sudo apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server basesite.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:57)
         port 443 namevhost basesite.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:57)
         port 443 namevhost sub1.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl_sub1_exa.conf:1)
         port 443 namevhost example.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl_exa.conf:1)
         port 443 namevhost sub2.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl_sub2_exa.conf:1)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server basesite.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:392)
         port 80 namevhost basesite.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:392)
         port 80 namevhost sub1.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:400)
                 alias sub1.example.com:80
         port 80 namevhost example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:407)
ServerRoot: "/etc/httpd"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html/"
Main ErrorLog: "/etc/httpd/logs/error_log"
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/httpd/" mechanism=default
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex cache-socache: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-opaque: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-client: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex authn-socache: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="nona_yo_biz" id=404
Group: name="nona_yo_biz" id=505
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I have resolved the problem and unfortunately it was a combination of trying several different things. So I don't have a simple answer to provide but I can provide some of the things that helped me along the way.

1. Thanks to Vasya Zhuryk I used **sudo apachectl -S** to determine where/how my virtualhosts were actually being loaded. In Amazon Linux apache default setup your ssl files are dynamically loaded from conf.d when they end in ".conf." They are loaded in from the main httpd.conf file via **IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf**. As i had previously realized, don't leave your backups in conf.d with ".conf" or you'll end up with problems. This does not however occur in the conf folder. So those need to be included with **Include /path to file/file.conf**.
2. I found that when private browsing in chrome (ctrl+shift+N), the non ssl sites worked fine. So clearing AutoFill Form Data (and possibly cached images and files) since "the beginning of time" cleared the bad domain redirect in chrome. It was very misleading because as I would type the address, the correct domain name would show but would always redirect to the wrong one. This is likely because of a previous poorly configured virtualhosts.

Again there were a lot of things done and tried along the way but the above were some key points that may help others.

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 idea:
(see virtual hosts)

```
1. httpd -S
```

And

```
2. SSLCertificateKeyFile must have *.key extension
```

You don`t have virtual host directive of rules(index.php, enabling .htaccess and other), you can try this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin support@example.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/basesite"
    ServerName basesite.com

    <Directory "/var/www/html/basesite/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: thanks, i was unaware of apachectl -S. I will add the output to my question above. I don't believe the .key thing is an issue because the https works fine and I found that in a guide somewhere pertaining to letsencrypt and amazon linux.

Comment: Should I add the directory to each *:80 virtual host? Also i thought they would inherrit from the global one in my config file <Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a entry for **NameVirtualHost *:80**, for name based virtualhost this is an entry you will need in your configuration file. Just give it a try.

Comment: I had tried that already. In apache 2.4 it has been removed from the documentation and threw a warning/error when I checked syntax. So I removed it without actually deploying it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "NS" record to domain admin panel.